# Boost.python building

Tags: python, boost, building

really can't understand, how to build correctly project that uses boost.python. I've included boost_(python/thread/system)-mt. Here is simple module file:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "script.hpp"
#include "boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp"

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(temp)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    py::def("PyLog", &engine::log);
}
```

Here is bulid log: http://dpaste.com/179232/.
Can't imagine what I forgot.

---

System: arch linux;

ls /usr/lib |grep boost :  http://dpaste.com/179233/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a missing library in link phase. All those undefined references are included in the Python library. You probably just need to add something like "-lpython2.5" to your last gcc command.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the headers from python itself.

The symbols such as `PySequence_GetSlice` and `PyExc_ValueError` are from the Python headers, not the boost::python headers.

That's all I can say, sorry. I don't really know boost::python. I'm surprised you don't have any error with "missing include file". I guess boost::python doesn't include the python headers itself?

btw, I saw the following on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/building.html

> Be sure not to #include any
>   system headers before wrap_python.hpp.
>   This restriction is actually imposed
>   by Python, or more properly, by
>   Python's interaction with your
>   operating system. See
>   http://docs.python.org/ext/simpleExample.html
>   for details.

maybe that can help?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but It doesn't help for now. wrap_python.hpp is included after all another stuff. And python-headers are included too.